# Meaning of “meno male”

Tags: meaning, phrase-request

I'm learning to speak Italian (along with my wife and 2 year old), and so we were watching Peppa Pig the other day.  We heard a phrase used that seemed like a response to “*mi dispiace*”, and we think it was “*meno male*.”  Is this roughly the equivalent to the English "no problem"/"no worries" after someone apologizes?  If not, what would be a phrase for this meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set somebody's mind at rest when they say «*Mi dispiace*», you might want to say «*Non ti preoccupare*», «*Non fa niente*», «*Figurati*». In some situations one could say – to look for something similar to *meno male* – «*Poco male*», as in «No (too much) harm done».

Answer (score 6):

"meno male" is not the equivalent of "no problem" / "no worries".

This phrase is used when you want to explain that you have prevented a possible situation.

An Italian synonym of "Meno male" is "Per fortuna".

Examples:

(ITA)

- Meno male che ho studiato altrimenti non avrei risposto alle domande.
- Meno male che ho portato l'ombrello altrimenti mi sarei bagnato.

(ENG)

- Fortunately, I have studied otherwise I would not have answered questions.
- Fortunately, I brought my umbrella otherwise I would have gotten wet.

Answer (score 5):

Another sense to add:

"meno male" has the same sense of the retort in English "coulda been worse", as in, this is "meno male" (less bad) than it could have been.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!